# Como deixar DIV "Responsiva"?

Tags: css, layout-responsivo

Não sei quase nada do, diagmos, "Avançado" do `CSS`!

Então eu queria saber como deixar uma `div` bem Responsiva para usuários `MOBILE`. O negócio é o seguinte:

Tenho Divs com algumas imagens, e uns `radios`, para escolha de detalhes etc! Essas `divs` estão de um tamanho só, que fica bem ajustada a tela do meu notebook! Mas eu quero fazer com que essas `divs` fiquem bem ajustadas com o `panel` da página em todos os dispositivos!

Meu código está assim:

```css
.selecao-bordas {

left: 300px; 
top: 150px; 
width: 715px; 
height: 100px;
overflow: auto;

}

.selecao-details {

left: 300px; 
top: 150px; 
width: 715px; 
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;

}
```

```html
<form>
    <br>
    Bordas
    <div class="selecao-bordas">
        <?php include("bordas.php"); ?>
    </div>
      
    <br>
    Detalhes
    
    <div class="selecao-details">
        <?php include("detalhes.php"); ?>
    </div>
        
    <br>
    Nível do Clã
    
    <?php include("clanlevel.php"); ?>
    
</form>
```

Um print de como fica na página:

http://image.prntscr.com/image/74d4235e915a43e3af1a987e70da9e62.png

Assim ele fica quando a tela diminui:

http://image.prntscr.com/image/92a0c3d6dedd4b928f3c5011b938722f.png

Comment: Ja pensou em usar bootstrap e o sistema de grid dele?

Comment: Uso Bootstrap, isso nem passou pela minha cabeça cara o, vou tentar aqui!

Comment: Como eu posso testar um site em vários tamanhos?

Comment: Mas tipo, como vou fazer pra deixar as colunas com a scroll-bar? sempre se ajustando?

Comment: No chrome, no console de desenvolvedor(clique com botão direito, inspecionar elemento), haverá dois icones na aba superior do lado esquerdo. O primeiro é uma seta em um quadrado o outro é a imagem de um celular e um tablet. Clique na imagem do celular e tablet. Ai vc ja esta no modo responsivo do chrome, vai ver que da pra aumentar e diminuir o tamanho da tela sem alterar o tamanho do browser inteiro. Além de selecionar um tamanho especifico de tela como de um iphone 6, de uma olhada nesse link https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports

Comment: ah vlw vou tentar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que isso ja resolve.

```
.selecao-bordas, .selecao-details {
    overflow: auto;
}
.content {
    display: inline-block;
}


<div class="container">
    <form>
        <br>
        Bordas
        <div class="selecao-bordas col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="content">
                <?php include("bordas.php"); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        Detalhes

        <div class="selecao-details col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="content">
                <?php include("detalhes.php"); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        Nível do Clã

        <?php include("clanlevel.php"); ?>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: cara, nao mudou nada, a selecao details ta ate perfeitinha, mas quero diminuir ela, para fazer que nem na print, a scroll-bar e a selecao bordas esta ultrapassando o panel

Comment: Tente colocar `position: relative` tanto nas selecoes quanto nos content. Ajudar sem ver ainda é difícil pra mim haha

Comment: http://prntscr.com/d0914f

Comment: No mobile fica assim: http://prntscr.com/d0927l

Comment: Daqui a umas horas eu vejo. Tô saindo do trampo

Comment: ppo cara to tentando de tudo, e nada funciona, do jeito que eu começei tava perfeito, mas só na minha tela

Comment: Tem como você colocar o html gerado do conteúdo da div que esta estourando o container. joga ele aqui https://codeshare.io/6Iiml daqui 10m eu volto e te ajudo.

Comment: cara, para facilitar o negocio, adicionei um well para saber o que esta rolando e tals, ai percebi que o unico problema e o table das imagens que ultrapassa o container e o panel

Comment: prontinho, ja coloquei o basico

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47621/discussion-between-giovane-and-sampaio-leal).